# How can I append/concatenate BLOB data to a BLOB column using update?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need to append data to my BLOB field, how can I do this using an `update`? What I am asking is; is it possible to concatenate blob data so that I can update a blob field with this new data. Something like:

```
UPDATE BLOB_table 
   SET BLOB_field = BLOB_field + BLOB_data
```

Answer (score 6):

Concat should work..

```
UPDATE BLOB_table SET BLOB_field = CONCAT(BLOB_field, BLOB_data);
```

I tested with this:

```
CREATE TABLE `Blobs` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `b` blob,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) 

insert into Blobs values (1, "heel");

update Blobs set b = concat(b, "heelele");
```

Maybe this just works since I paste strings into the Blob...

Comment: No, its not working for me. If you have some code snippet then please share.

Comment: Looks like someone else has made it work: http://grokbase.com/t/mysql/mysql/996xt29byb/blobs-and-concat

Comment: This often runs into the error "Result of CONCAT exceeds max-packet_size". Basically, it's not possible to stream large data into and out of MySQL/MariaDB.