# Peewee CompressedField gets truncated on MySQL db

Tags: python, mysql, peewee, pymysql

I'm using Peewee with PyMySQL and I'm getting stuck on the 64k `blob` size when trying to use the `CompressedField` from the `playhouse` module...

The following code gives me truncated data for the second test

```
from peewee import *
from playhouse.db_url import connect
from playhouse.fields import CompressedField

db = connect("mysql://me:pass@IP/test_db")

class Compress(Model):
    name = CharField()
    cmprssd_data = CompressedField()

    class Meta:
        database = db

db.connect()
db.create_tables([Compress], safe=True)

short_str = "".zfill(200)
di_test1 = {"name": "first", "cmprssd_data": short_str }
test1 = Compress(**di_test1)
test1.save()

long_str = "".zfill(200000000)
di_test2 = {"name": "second", "cmprssd_data": long_str }
test2 = Compress(**di_test2)
test2.save()
```

I tried updating `'max_allowed_packet'` to `1073741824` in both MySQL and pymysql but this did not change anything.
By the way, as I think it's the same problem, using the `long_str` with a `PickledField` gives me a broken pipe error.

Is there a way of telling peewee to work with `longblob`? (or does the problem come from somewhere else?)
I also found a [thread on the broken pipe problem with pymysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13376559/broken-pipe-when-i-try-to-insert-large-blob-with-pymysql) but I don't know how to tell a Peewee model to do the chunk stuff on that specific field...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished with a [custom field](https://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/peewee/models.html#creating-a-custom-field):

```
from peewee import *
from playhouse.fields import CompressedField

# tell database that the longblob column type exists
db = MySQLDatabase('test', host='127.0.0.1', user='root',
                   fields={'longblob': 'longblob'})


# create a custom field, in this case subclassing the existing field
class LongCompressedField(CompressedField):
    db_field = 'longblob'  # <-- this matches our dictionary key above


class MyModel(Model):
    val = LongCompressedField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'test'
        database = db


db.connect()
db.create_table(MyModel, safe=True)

m = MyModel(val=''.zfill(200000000))
m.save()
```